# Google Drive Python API without Creating Project

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

For the Google Drive Python API, in all the tutorials I have seen, they require
users to create a project in their Google Dashboard, before obtaining a client ID and a client secret json file. I've been researching both the default Google Drive API and the pydrive module.

Is there a way for users to simply login to their Google Account with username and password,
without having to create a project? So once they login to their Google Account, they are free to
access all files in their Google Drive?

Comment: Nope, you need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use the Drive API without creating a GCP project for the application. Otherwise Google has no idea what application is requesting access, and what scope of account access it should have.

Using simply a username and password to log in is not possible. You need to create a project and use OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

it might be possible using some pysimplegui hackery  or just simply modifying the code of a python based browser    but in most cases it is not practical

except if you need to automate something (like renaming files ) that would take 1 hour  in a place where you do not have access to GCP

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).